# problem with xpath results

Tags: xpath

i'm trying to get the maximal book value (attached dtd) but i could only get the value not the node itself
i used this command

```
max(//price)
```

but i got the value not the node.

this is the dtd

```
<!ELEMENT iventory (book)+>
<!ELEMENT book (title,author+,publisher+,price,chapter*)>
<!ATTLIST book num ID #REQUIRED>
<!ELEMENT chapter (title,(paragraph*|section))>
<!ELEMENT section (title?,paragraph*)>
<!ELEMENT title (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT author (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT publisher (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT price (#PCDATA)>
<!ATTLIST price  currency  CDATA #FIXED "usd">
<!ELEMENT paragraph (#PCDATA|emph|image)*>
<!ELEMENT emph (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT image EMPTY>
<!ATTLIST image file CDATA #REQUIRED
            height CDATA #IMPLIED
            width  CDATA #IMPLIED>
```

another thing i need to find is all the books that their price is higher then the book preceding book, i tried many ways but hoe can i get the next node?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you use XPath 1.0 or 2.0? `max` is XPath 2.0, isn't it? And often XPath 2.0 implementations also support XQuery 1.0 so that way you could simply do

```
let $max-price := max(/inventory/book/price)
return /inventory/book[price = $max-price]
```

to get the or those book elements having the maximum price.

If you need to use pure XPath 2.0 then of course

```
/inventory/book[price = max(../book/price)]
```

should do, it might be inefficient.

As for your second question, does

```
/inventory/book[price > preceding-sibling::book[1]/price]
```

do what you want?

Comment: I would expect from an XPath 2.0 engine some kind of optimization when dealing with absolute expression... So, I would go with `/inventory/book[price = max(/inventory/book/price)]`

Answer (score 0):

With another approach, you could use this XPath 2.0 expression:

```
/inventory/book[index-of(/inventory/book/price,max(/inventory/book/price))[1]]
```